# How to concurrently load and render data one by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, electron, react-hooks

I want to find a way to fill up a table with data that I load at the press of a button. The data is loaded by processing a bunch of files. Each item of data takes about a quarter of a second to load.

Currently, I'm using a functional component for the whole page and hooks for state. I would like to load and render the data one by one, but when I (the user) begin loading, the app freezes and I cannot click away to even X out the app. After loading, however, the app resumes with the collected data.

I've tried a few different solutions, and I'll detail the reasons each of them fail.

**Suspense or lazy loading:**
The idea is to load the next item as soon as it's ready. These solutions require that all the data is rendered at the same time once it is all loaded. I'm looking for a way to render each item one at a time as they are loaded.

**Generators/Callbacks:**
When the button is clicked and the function for loading data is begun, the app freezes until all data is loaded.

**Promises:**
I could be using it wrong. I'm under the impression that each item would require a separate promise. I'll then have to use one of the solutions above for the whole.

**React useEffect:**
Not sure how this could help the state update and re-render with each callback.

```
export function loadTheData(callback) {
  for (const file of getFiles()) {
    callback(file);
  }
}
```

getFiles is a generator function.

```js
import React, { useState, useReducer, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import { loadTheData} from '../../actions/data';
import Page from '../common/Page';

export default function MyComp() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  function loadData() {
    if (isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);

    loadTheData(item => { // loadTheData is an external function
      setData(prevData => [...prevData, item]);
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <Page>
      <Button
        onClick={loadData}
        loading={isLoading}
      />
      <p>{data.length}</p>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

I expect the data.length value to increase one by one until it's complete after I press the button, but instead it is frozen at 0 until the end when it changes to the correct data length. The loadTheData function provides the data one at a time into the callback function. I know the loadTheData function and other parts of the code work properly. I'm just not sure how to go about concurrently/asynchronously loading *and* rendering the data that is loaded.

Comment: can you post the implementation of `loadTheData` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone new to Electron who comes across this, I came back to this project recently and found a better definition of the real problem I had.

It turns out the main UI thread was being blocked by my "loadTheData" function, and no alternative method of using the function with Promises or otherwise could change that.

This link details the issue more: [Electron: Blocking the main process](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/performance#3-blocking-the-main-process)

It turns out that in order to "concurrently load and render data one by one," one needs to follow the steps from the linked online guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadTheData` function should look like this

```
function loadTheData(cb) {
   return Promise.all(getFiles().map(file => api.call().then(cb)))
}
```

Then use it in the component like this

```
  async function loadData() {
    if (isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);

    await loadTheData(item => { // loadTheData is an external function
      setData(prevData => [...prevData, item]);
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
```

Comment: I added the loadTheData function that I'm currently using. Your answer makes sense, but how can I use Promise.all with a generator since I'm getting the files with a loop?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your use case of having arrray of files as basis for api requests. You don't need generators for this. Using generators comes with coroutines to `yield ` promises